# VueJS v-model not working on select tag when bound with dynamic property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I am building an application which will generate a dynamic form for customer feedback reception. Now while adding fields to the form, individual fields have validation rules inlcuding `length` and `type` rules, there is also going to be a property on each validation rule, which will determine if that particular rule should be parsed while validating the fields.

I have a Vue data property called `fields`, which has an object for each field. It looks like this:

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            fields: [{
                label: 'Email',
                validation: {
                    length: {
                        add: 0, // 0 for false, 1 for true
                        min: 0, // minimum length
                        max: 0 // maximum length
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }

}
```

Now for enabling the user to select whether validation rule should be enabled or disabled (i.e `length.add = 1 or 0`) , I have a a `select` element with two options for their respective values (`0` and `1`). Here is the template code:

```html
<div v-for="(field, index) in fields">
    <div v-for="(rule, key) in field.validation">
       <select class="form-control" v-model="fields[index].validation[key].add">
         <option :value="1">Enabled</option>
         <option :value="0">Disabled</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine such as the `v-model` on `select` is mutating the value in the data property, but the `select` isn't showing the default value which is selected, here is what it looks like after rendering:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why isn't it working? I also tried replacing `v-model` with the `value` attribute, but no luck!

Comment: works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mzLj1bs7/

Comment: @Deda Weird! This is the same code in my application, but it isn't working!

Comment: Maybe relevant to `vue` version !? not sure

Comment: @talkhabi Vue version is `2.6.10`

Comment: btw you are missing `key` values in both loops.

Comment: @Deda I do have the :key attrs, just not in this code, But yeah I don't have :key  on the inner loop

Comment: My guess would be a type mismatch. Is there any chance that in your real code you've got strings for `'0'` or `'1'` creeping in rather than numbers?

Comment: What CSS style have you applied on your select tag?
As @Deda, it works fine (even without :key fields) on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Sackey it is just plain Bootstrap `form-control`

Comment: @skirtle Chek this out, these are the data properties, showing numbers and not strings. image: https://ibb.co/x1wBsQQ

Comment: Make sure the `fields[index].validation[key].add` is `0` or `1`, to test this just do `<select data-value="fields[index].validation[key].add">` and check the attr value in html.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you should try the `:key` attribute in the options field. Set there the value for the key. The first option should have the value `0` and the second option should have the value `1`. Now there should be a mapping between the values.

```
<div v-for="(field, index) in fields">
    <div v-for="(rule, key) in field.validation">
       <select class="form-control" v-model="fields[index].validation[key].add">
         <option :key="1" :value="1">Enabled</option>
         <option :value="0" :value="0">Disabled</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```